# Cocos2d Accelerometer Movement

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering how you would move a `CCSprite` right and left by tilting the device right and left.  Like in the falling balls app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution provided is dependent on Chipmonk which is a 2d physics engine. The accelerometer can be used to move a CCSprite without the need of a physics engine. There are several ways to achieve what you want.

This is a great blog with awesome tutorials to get you moving in the right direction.

[http://www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
[http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:using_accelerometer_for_sprite_movement](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3ausing_accelerometer_for_sprite_movement)

it is an example code to move the sprite on a plane surface along the x and y accelerometer axis as per the tilt.